# Creating SAS BI Dashboard accounts for people outside our organization?

Tags: authentication, sas, business-intelligence, account

our organization has been using SAS BI Dashboard for several months now for internal use within our own organization.  Now, we are working on a project where roughly 100 people in *other*, outside organizations will need to log on to our BI Dashboard site to view an *individualized* dashboard for their organization.  We plan to use row-level permissions in an Information Map to control who is allowed to see what in terms of the data behind the dashboard indicators.

How would you recommend creating roughly 100 individual log-ons for outside users?

Is there a way to automate the process rather than manually creating all the accounts?

If I create the log-on name and password for each outside user, how/where would I store that in Management Console?

Any help would be appreciated - our office is small enough that we do not have a dedicated IT person or fully-trained SAS administrator, so I'm in over my head.  Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a good Stack Overflow question, as it is basically "teach me how to use a product" - far too inspecific for here.  This is a more appropriate question for the SAS community forums, although I have a great concern that what you really need is to hire a SAS consultant to perform some of these tasks - if you're not capable of figuring this stuff out from online documentation, you likely require significantly more help than you'll get from any sort of free solution like this.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, @Joe, that a SAS consultant would be a better way to go.  Unfortunately, we do not have the resources or time to make that happen right now.  I posted the question in hopes of getting pointed in the right direction because I have not been able to figure it out myself from what I've read so far.  If Stack Overflow is the wrong venue, I understand and apologize for misusing this resource.

Comment: communities.sas.com is more likely to be helpful (as they include more broad questions like this).  You also may want to contact your SAS site rep and see if they can give you any advice - there may be SAS resources you can use at lower cost than a full consultant.  Realistically, though, the cost of SAS BI Dashboard is high enough that I can't understand not wanting to hire a consultant to set it up for you - spending six figures on a software and then not setting it up properly seems shortsighted.

Comment: I agree with the comments above; this is fairly indepth.  One thing to consider is your license.  Not all licenses allow you to use the SAS portal for outside reporting.  While you are investigating how to do this, make sure you are able to do this without violating your license and opening your organization to potential legal action.

Answer (score 1):

As an ex SAS consultant, I can tell you briefly how I have solved this problem.
First, creating the users in batch should be easy. There are tons of scripts out there that will teach you this. I would recommend to create them in your LDAP server (probably Active Directory), to have them in a central place. That way, you can treat them the same way as you do the internal users.
To get them into the metadataserver, you should take a look at the macros that SAS provides for this:
The following macros are the core components used to import and synchronize user accounts from Active Directory to SAS metadata: %MDUIMPC , %MDUIMPLB , %MDUEXTR , %MDUCMP , %MDUCHGV , %MDUCHGLB. They are located in the following directory: [SAS Home]\SASFoundation\9.3\core\sasmacro.
This SGF proceeding will give you a practical description of the process:
http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/377-2012.pdf

As for the question you did not ask, "how to present the BI Dashboard webapplication to the external users". You need to set up a reverse proxy web server in a secure zone (DMZ). See this document for details: http://support.sas.com/resources/thirdpartysupport/v92m3/appservers/ApacheProxyJBoss.pdf

Hope this helps!
Stig

Comment: Thanks for the information, @Stig!  Because we needed at least a short-term solution and were having issues with metadata trying to link up with Active Directory, we ended up creating SAS accounts based on local Windows user accounts, so that the SAS account user ID included the domain of the server running our public Enterprise BI Platform - for example, "WIN\Smith01" or "ORG-SASDMZ\Smith01".  We hope to look into long-term solutions more like what you suggested down the road.  Thanks again!